# Update scope variable in directive not updating the visual

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple slideshow. I introduced a new scope variable called 'isLoading'. The idea is to disable the Next button until the image is fully loaded. However the Next button remains disabled. The UI is not detecting that the scope variable has changed.

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src='angular.min.js'></script>
    
    <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.slides = [
    {filename : 'Slide5.jpg', type : 'image'},
    {filename : 'Slide1.PNG', type : 'image'},
  ];
  $scope.page = 0;
  setCurrentSlide();
  $scope.previous = function() {
    $scope.page--;
    setCurrentSlide();
  };
  $scope.next = function() {
    $scope.page++;
    setCurrentSlide();
  };
  $scope.completed = function() {
    alert('done');
  };
  
  function setCurrentSlide() {
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    $scope.currentSlide = $scope.slides[$scope.page];
  }
});

app.directive('imgloader', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, ele) {
            ele.bind('load', function () {
                scope.isLoading = false;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
</script>
    
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <img imgloader ng-if="currentSlide.type == 'image'" src='{{currentSlide.filename}}'/>
        <video ng-if="currentSlide.type == 'video'" controls>
            <source src="{{currentSlide.filename}}"/>
        </video>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="controlscontainer">
            <span class="slidenumbers">Slide {{page+1}} / {{slides.length}}</span>
            <button ng-click="previous()" ng-disabled="page <= 0" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Previous</button>
            <button ng-click="next()" ng-disabled="isLoading || page >= slides.length-1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Next</button>
            <button ng-click="completed()" ng-disabled="page != slides.length-1" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Complete</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've expiremented with calling scope.$apply() within the ele.bind() after changing the isLoading variable. Has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the scope of your directive with the $scope of your controller:
notice that this 2 reffer to different contexts scope.isLoading !== $scope.isLoading
instead you colud try:

```
<img ng-load="isLoading = false" ng-if="currentSlide.type == 'image'" src='{{currentSlide.filename}}'/>
```

Where isLoading referes to the property on the $scope of your controller